# How to match a parent node based on the text of the child node in React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am trying to write some tests for two lists of users (users and members, identical markup, different semantic content) in React Testing Library. Details of each user are inside of a `span` element.

**I have this DOM tree:**

```
<div>
   <span>
      <div>
        <b>Text 1</b>
      </div>
      <div>
        <!-- other elements here -->
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<div>
   <span>
      <div>
        <b>Text 2</b>
      </div>
      <div>
        <!-- other elements here -->
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<div>
   <span>
      <div>
        <b>Text 3</b>
      </div>
      <div>
        <!-- other elements here -->
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

I want to match the `span` element (because it handles the `onClick` logic) based on the text inside the `b` child element (because it contains user's name and last name).

**I tried doing it this way:**

```
const getUsersLists = (doc) => ({
  usersList: doc.querySelector('.users-users-list'),
  membersList: doc.querySelector('.members-users-list'),
});

const getUser = (name, list) => (
  screen.findByText(name), { selector: 'span' }, { container: list })
);

test('users exist', () => {
  const { usersList } = getUsersLists(document); 

  const sampleUser = await getUser('Text 1', usersList);

  expect(sampleUser).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**The problem:**

Those matchers successfully find the `Text 1` text if I remove the `{ selector: 'span' }` options object from the `getUser` method. As soon as I tell RTL to look for a `span` element it can't find anything.

I also want to avoid any more `document.querySelector` and class / ID (including `data-testid`) references.